# SOQL Profile Names, Permission Set, User Name

Tags: salesforce, workbench, soql

I am accustomed to using SQL, and have been thrown into the SOQL Salesforce realm quickly without much idea on how to use SOQL.

I have been trying to create a simple query to get the above fields all in one table so that I can see for each user their profile name, user name and the permission set that they have. This is a simple query but using workbench I have not been able to get it. Thanks!

Comment: The way you present your question here looks to me like a bit too little effort from your side. I might be wrong, so I suggest adding a concrete example of what you tried so far, what worked and what did not. Where you read about possible solutions and where you got stuck exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FirstName,LastName,PortalRole, ProfileId, Profile.Name, Profile.userType, Username, UserRoleId,UserType, Profile.PermissionsAccessCMC, Profile.PermissionsActivateContract,Profile.PermissionsActivitiesAccess FROM User
```

That is you can get all the permission from profile table. In the above SOQL, I have added some of the permission fields from profile.